# How to unselect value from ui-select component in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

- I have created a UI select field using PHP, with the below code of lines.

  ```
  $data = [
       'arguments' => [
           'data' => [
               'config' => [
                   'label' => __('Options'),
                   'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                   'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                   'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select',
                   'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                   'selectType' => 'simple',
                   'selectType' => $this->getOptions(),
                   'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                   'sortOrder' => 10,
                   'disableLabel' => true,
                   'multiple' => false,
                   'selectedPlaceholders' => [
                       'defaultPlaceholder' => __('None'),
                   ],
                   'validation' => [
                       'required-entry' => false
                   ],
                   'source' => 'vendorfield',
                   'visible' => 1,
                   'required' => 0,
                   'filterOptions' => true
               ],
           ],
       ],
   ];
  ```
- When the user selects one of the options from the Dropdown then that option will be selected.
- Now if the user wants to **unselect** that option. I mean users **don`t want** to select any value from that dropdown. then what?
- Currently, the user **can`t unselect** the selected value.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Add another option value with empty data that will be treated as no select or add option with "Select from dropdown" that will be treated as no value selected

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no option to unselect a dropdown.

You can add an initial empty value in that dropdown like "Please select a value" so that the admin can easily choose that value whenever they want to unselect the dropdown.

The dropdown option should be `["label" => "Please select a value", "value" => ""]`

This option should be placed as the first option in that option dropdown. You can done this inside the "`$this->getOptions()`" function.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have already tried this way but the **Option is not listed in the Dropdown**.
Here is an Options array: https://i.imgur.com/C2aQBnJ.png